# Apply Relu to an input without using lambda layer?

Tags: python, lambda, keras, keras-layer

I am currently having some issue loading my model, as it includes a lambda layer..

This is my neural network layer which uses lambda layer.

```
#
#   Python scritpt -  Keras RCNN model.
#
import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation
from keras.layers import merge, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import add
from keras import backend as K


#   RCL:
#   BatchNorm(Relu(conv(L-1) + conv(L)))
#

def make_RCNN(input,number_of_rcl,num_of_filter, filtersize,alpha,pool):
    feed_forward = Conv2D(filters=num_of_filter, kernel_size=1, name='init')(input)

    for x in xrange(number_of_rcl):
        output = RCL(feed_forward,num_of_filter,filtersize,alpha,pool)
        feed_forward = output

    return feed_forward

def RCL(feed_forward_input,num_of_filter, filtersize, alpha,pool):
    conv = Conv2D(filters=num_of_filter, kernel_size=filtersize, padding='same')
    recurrent_input = conv(feed_forward_input)
    merged = add([feed_forward_input,recurrent_input])
    conv_relu = Lambda(lambda x : K.relu(x,alpha=alpha))(merged)
    conv_relu_batchnorm = BatchNormalization()(conv_relu)
    if pool:
        conv_relu_batchnorm_pool = MaxPooling2D()(conv_relu_batchnorm)
        return conv_relu_batchnorm_pool
    else:

        return conv_relu_batchnorm

input = Input(shape=(30,30,3))
output = make_RCNN(input,number_of_rcl=3,num_of_filter=3,filtersize=3,alpha=0.2, pool=True)

model = Model(input = input, output = output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

how do i remove the layer, without altering the functionality?...

Comment: Use an activation layer as described here: https://keras.io/activations/

Comment: how do I pass alpha values ? @Wilco

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252495/keras-how-to-use-max-value-in-relu-activation-function

Comment: What is the error when you load the model ? normaly you can save lambda layers and restore them with load_model()...

Comment: arg 5 (closure) must be none or tuple keras  @NassimBen

Comment: https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/